# Entity Framework - ensure NO updates made

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am using WebAPI2 (C#) and want to use the following code in a Controller (ignore for now the fact that it is best practice to use some "ViewModel" equivalent separation...)

```
Playlist p = await _db.Playlists.FindAsync(id);
p.Videos.ForEach(x => x.playlists = null);
return Ok(p);
```

The `Playlist` and `Video` classes, using EF, have a Many-to-Many relationship via navigation properties.

**Can I be 100% certain that, once I set the playlists to null (line #2), the DB will NOT be updated? (i.e. won't nullify each `Video.playlists` property)**

Obviously I'm not calling SaveChanges...but EF still tracks the object I believe...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`AsNoTracking()` extension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679352(v=vs.103).aspx), but you cannot use `FindAsync` with that.

```
Playlist p = await _db.Playlists.AsNoTracking().SingleOrDefault(p => p.Id == id);
p.Videos.ForEach(x => x.playlists = null);
return Ok(p);
```

Answer (score 1):

Disable lazy loading and don't `Include` the playlists:

```
_db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
Playlist p = await _db.Playlists.FindAsync(id);
```

Now you don't even have to clear the playlists.

Note however that it's still not safe to add items to the play lists. They might get saved somehow. So using `AsNoTracking` on top of this is still recommended.

Comment: if lazy loading is disabled, do you mean that the Videos (navigation property of Playlists) won't be accessible? Thanks for the additional answer.

Comment: If there are no play lists, how can their `Videos` property be accessible? Anyway, it doesn't change anything in your objects structure, the only thing is that the playlists aren't loaded, so you achieve what you want in fewer steps. It's pointless to load the lists first and then clear them.

Comment: not sure if you mean something else...but Playlists exist, I just can't return the object as is (with Videos, which in turn reference Playlists) , because it will cause a recursive loop when serializing to JSON. Hence the desire to set the Video.playlists to null temporarily.

Comment: You should have said that it's in a context of serialization. For serialization lazy loading and tracking should always be disabled. A serializer will traverse these circular references infinitely because (with tracking) EF populates them by relationship fixup.